# limit jquery random image with MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a little trouble in here, I have some script that I taken from this link [jQuery, random div order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436445/1099048), this script I used for call my query's with MySQL.

My problem is, for example I have 8 records but I already limit only 4 records to displayed and I want all records can be displayed even I already limit to displayed it. How?

here for my model

```
public function get_ads_query(){
    $row = $this->db->get('advertise');

    return $row;

}
```

here is my code in view

```
<div id="advertentie" class="advcontainer">
    <?php 
        $row = $this->M_front->get_ads_query();
        $row = $row->result();
        foreach($row as $ads):
    ?>
    <div class="adblock"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/advertise/<?php echo $ads->Picture; ?>" /></div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

and here the jquery

```
var $container = $(".advcontainer");

setInterval(function(){
    $container.html(shuffle($container.children().get()));
}, 1500);
$(".advcontainer div").each(function(){
    var color = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: color});
});
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, eventually with patience and use the power of google and than found this link [show and hide several random divs using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257204/1099048). Once again thank you so much **stackoverflow**